# Meaning of "to be sporting designer stubble"

Tags: meaning

Consider:

> *She has no dress sense or personal hygiene standards. There's no need for any woman **to be sporting  designer stubble** and go around smelling of Jeyes fluid and hamster droppings.*

I am not able to fully understand the second sentence from the above excerpt. I presume that the second sentence develops the description of the first one in an offensive way. But the passage in bold does not make any sense to me. "Designer stubble" should be related to men after all. Can you explain to me the meaning of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*To sport*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sport) is to wear or display something, usually something distinctive.

["Designer stubble"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designer_stubble) is trimmed facial hair which is still visible but not very long.

---

Some women grow small amounts of hair on their face, especially as they get older. The author here is stating that not removing this hair – by shaving, plucking, waxing, what have you – is unhygienic. They're also exaggerating to convey that this woman grows more facial hair than they consider normal – the woman probably doesn't *literally* have designer stubble, but she might have some noticeable facial hair.

Compare with other physical feature-related exaggerations, like "*skinny as a rake*," which compares someone's diameter to that of the handle of a garden rake. The person isn't literally as skinny as a garden rake, but the exaggeration gives you the idea that they are very skinny.

Answer (score 2):

In normal usage yes, but here the author is portraying an unflattering picture.

Women do remove hair from, for example, armpits. So we could read this as implying that the person described has neglected to do this sufficiently often (in the offensive opinion of the author).

Comment: Could be the legs as well, depending on the location and local customs.